# Distribution of a function of a binomial random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, expected-value, binomial-distribution

Let $X$ be a random variable which is the difference of two binomial random variables, $$X=Y_1-Y_2,\\
Y_1\sim {\rm Binomial}(n,p_1),\\
Y_2\sim {\rm Binomial}(n,p_2).$$

Note that the first parameter of the binomial distribution is the same ($n$) for both $Y_1$ and $Y_2$. Is it possible to compute the distribution of $Z=\log(1 + e^X)$ ?
If not the distribution, can we at least compute the expectation $\mathbb{E}[Z]$ or say anything about it?

Comment: You can compute an upper bound on $\mathbb{E}[Z]$ using Jensen's inequality and the MGF of a Binomial distribution. Would that be interesting?